# spring remoting with rabbitmq request-reply pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

Is Spring Remoting with RabbitMQ not supported on the latest Spring version? What is the alternative for this?

What is the alternative for this?

I want to implement the request-reply pattern for microservices (SOA architecture) using RabbitMQ.

Comment: Remoting has been removed in Spring 6 due to the security risks it involved. So it isn't supported anymore because the underlying infrastructure has been removed from Spring itself, hence Srping AMQP cannot support it anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum THANKS,
but i want to implement request-reply pattern for microservices (SOA architecture) using RabbitMQ so i need to create a new queue for every rest endpoint?

Comment: Or re-instate the remoting support in your own repository (spring is open source so the code for remoting is still available in the 5.3 branch of Spring, which you could copy).

Comment: @M.Deinum no i don't want to use removing tech by spring.